# Merging multiple data sources for a line graph in Excel and working with uneven data sizes

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have 15ish data sources that contain a date and some values. But the dates can be different from one sheet to another.

Sheet 1

| Date | Infected |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-03-28 | 10 |
| 2020-03-29 | 20 |
| ... |  |

Sheet 2

| Date | Infected |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-04-15 | 5 |
| 2020-04-16 | 7 |
| ... |  |

My goal is to produce a combined line graph containing all the sheets, but some tables have more data than others with the date series.

I can think of only one option to make them all the same size and cover all date values: [Merge queries](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/merge-queries-power-query-fd157620-5470-4c0f-b132-7ca2616d17f9) in Power Query (essentially many left joins to bring all sheets together and combine all the dates).

Is there another option I'm missing to combine these tables? Something at the graph level maybe so they can all refer to their own date series?

Answer (score 0):

**Tables that are structured like this and stored in different worksheets can be merged using the pivot function.** Here are **2 scenarios** based on the assumption each table is saved on a separate worksheet within a single Excel workbook:

**1. Each table is saved as an Excel Table**. The Tables are combined into a single table using Power Query and the resulting table is then loaded into a new worksheet.

**2. The tables are not saved as Excel Tables**, and doing this manually or figuring out how to execute this process with a VBA script seems like a lot of work. In this case, the tables can be more easily combined by creating a new Excel workbook and then connecting to the file containing the tables by using Power Query.

Here is an example for each scenario. The dataset consists of 3 tables each containing 10 rows where the dates between tables overlap a bit.

#### Scenario 1 - Data stored in Excel Tables

Here is what the sample data looks like in the first worksheet containing an Excel Table named `Source1`:

[image: tables_Source1]

With all tables saved as Excel Tables and named following the same convention, it is time to open the Power Query Editor and complete the following steps:

- Create a blank query and type `= Excel.CurrentWorkbook()` in the formula bar to list all the named objects contained in the workbook.

[image: list_tables]

- Filter the Name column to keep only rows with names starting with `Source` to avoid including the table combining all the data into this query once it is completed and refreshed.
- Click on the expand button of the Date column, uncheck *Use original column name as prefix* and click OK.
- Change the Date column data type to *date*.
- Pivot the Name column with the Infected column as the Values Column and with *Don't Aggregate* selected under Advanced Options.

[image: pivot]

Now the data is merged appropriately and can be loaded in a new worksheet to create the line graph:

[image: combinedtables_graph]

Here is the M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(Source, each Text.StartsWith([Name], "Source")),
    #"Expanded Content" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "Content", {"Date", "Infected"}, {"Date", "Infected"}),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded Content",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Changed Type", List.Distinct(#"Changed Type"[Name]), "Name", "Infected")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

#### Scenario 2 - Data not stored in Excel Tables

In this scenario, the data is stored in an external Excel workbook `datasources.xlsx`. Here is what the sample data looks like in the first worksheet:

[image: datasources_sheet1]

In a separate Excel workbook, open the Power Query Editor and complete the following steps:

- Create a blank query and type the following line in the formula bar using the appropriate file path: `= Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\FilePath\datasources.xlsx"))`

[image: datasources]

- Remove all columns except Name and Data.
- Click on the expand button of the Data column, uncheck *Use original column name as prefix* and click OK.
- Promote the first row to column headers.
- Edit the data types for the Date and Infected columns.
- Select the Date column and remove rows containing errors.
- Pivot the Sheet1 column with the Infected column as the Values Column and with *Don't Aggregate* selected under Advanced Options.

Now the data is merged appropriately and can be loaded in a new worksheet to create the line graph, yielding the same result as in Scenario 1 except for the column headers and legend labels:

[image: combinedsheets_graph]

Here is the M code:

```
let
    Source = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\FilePath\datasources.xlsx")),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(Source,{"Item", "Kind", "Hidden"}),
    #"Expanded Data" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Removed Columns", "Data", {"Column1", "Column2"}, {"Column1", "Column2"}),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Expanded Data", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Promoted Headers",{{"Sheet1", type text}, {"Date", type date}, {"Infected", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Removed Errors" = Table.RemoveRowsWithErrors(#"Changed Type", {"Date"}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Removed Errors", List.Distinct(#"Removed Errors"[Sheet1]), "Sheet1", "Infected")
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```